# Call smarty block from string stored in database

Tags: php, database, smarty

Hi is there a way to call smarty plugin or block from string stored in database? I tried {eval} it works great, but I cant get plugins to be loaded on place selected in string.

Example:

```
text
{contact_form}
text
picture
{register_form}
```

I get:

```
text
text
picture
{contact_form}
{register_form}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend 'string:' to the template code and pass that to fetch() instead of an actual template file:

```
$tpl = <<<EOT
text
{contact_form}
text
picture
{register_form}
EOT;

echo $smarty->fetch('string:' . $tpl);
```